# Not able to publish ArcGIS Server as a map service using ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Server 10.2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.0 and an old ArcGIS for Server Advanced - 10.2.0 (build 3370). enabled with ArcGIS out of the box self assigned certificate 
I am able to connect the server into the ArcGIS Pro with ArcGIS Server **Administrator** account, as you can see from this screenshot

[image]

**But** there are some issue happening here:
**1 - First of all**, I am not able to change the Type of connection
[image]

**2 - Secondly**, I am seeing only one Folder (**G**) on ArcGIS Pro while I have two others folders on service as

[image]

3- and Finally, I am not able to publish to the server even though I have logged into the ArcGIS Pro with ArcGIS Server Administrator Account

[image]

As you can see there is no **Publish** option in the window! Can you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: If you look at the compatibility docs, I expect you'll find that Pro 2.9 is Enterprise 10.9.1-ready, and admin-compatible back to 10.6.x. This is likely to happen when you use components eight years apart in lineage. Modifications needed to be made on both sides to support Pro, and Pro didn't exist back in the 10.2 timeframe.  You can try to talk to Tech Support, but since 10.2 has been retired since July 2019, you probably won't get far.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/71013694/820534

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you'd use ArcGIS Pro to connect and publish services to ArcGIS Enterprise (meaning all the components; Portal, Server and Web Adaptor). I believe support was added to publish to a stand alone server around 2.5-ish (give or take a release of Pro). The ArcGIS Pro [help from 2.7 references](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/help/projects/connect-to-a-gis-server.htm) that administrator connections can only be made to ArcGIS Server 10.6 and newer. (I can't find help older than 2.7, but the main fact is GIS Server needs to be 10.6 and you have 10.2. Thus, your scenario is impossible. You'll need to use ArcMap to publish)

> Publisher and administrator connections are only supported with
> stand-alone ArcGIS Server sites at 10.6 or later. With earlier
> versions, you can create connections that allow you to use services
> only. If you add a server connection to your project that was created
> in ArcMap, for example, a new server connection will be created in the
> project's home folder with user-level privileges. If you directly use
> one of the connections without adding it to a project first, the
> connection created by ArcGIS Pro will automatically be downgraded to a
> user-level connection, but the change will not be saved to the
> connection file.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you do not see the 'System' or 'Utility' folders (even signed in as admin) for publishing locations. No matter what version you are on. You can publish to root, or a folder you create. 'System' or 'Utility' folders are created during the ArcGIS server install and are used for utilities and system services. Therefore, I would expect to only see 'G' as an option aside from root.

Next, try to add a layer to the map, and then right click the layer and share as a web layer. It is not clear that this step is happening or not as a sharing option.

I am not sure if there will be a compatibility issue or not when sharing, but it is suspect that you can't see publish after adding an admin connection, and it maybe as others stated compatibility.